# Ruta no encontrada del chromedriver con ordenador mac

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

siempre he ejecutado el webdriver de chrome con feature de cucumber con Windows. Ahora usando el mismo código y con la ruta correcta (o eso parece), no encuentra el chromedriver.
Os paso el código de feature:

```
Feature: Google

    Scenario: Landing Page Test
    Given estoy en la pagina de Google
    When hago click en el menu
    And valido la pagina siguiente
```

Y este es el código de Java:

```
public class Inicio {
    public WebDriver driver;
    @Given("estoy en la pagina de Innocv")
    public void estoy_en_la_pagina_de_innocv() {
        
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(projectPath);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath+"/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.innocv.com/");
//      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        driver.manage().timeouts();;
    }

    @When("hago click en el menu")
    public void hago_click_en_el_menu() {
    
    }

    @When("valido la pagina siguiente")
    public void valido_la_pagina_siguiente() {
       
    }
}
```

Espero que me podéis ayudar.
Gracias!

Comment: Ya está solucionado!! En propiedades del chromedriver, debemos activar todos los permisos

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Añado una imagen sobre activar los permisos desde el chromedriver.
saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Estimado yo en lo personal deje de ocupar la ruta del driver fija en el proyecto y la volvi dinamica con una libreria.

Razones de las por que lo hice:

- Cuando se actualiza el navegador en tu pc tienes que cambiar a mano el driver para que tome la nueva version.
- El driver ocupa un espacio adicional en el repositorio.
- Cuando ejecutas en jenkins tienes grandes probalidades de que la version de la maquina virtual(El nodo) sea distinta a la version que soporta tu driver, provocando fallos en tus pruebas y un dolor de cabeza.

Con la libreria que te dejaré mas abajo evitas todo eso y vuelves mas robusta tu ejecucion.

https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/